# Find Out If There's More Using Google Reader API

Tags: google-reader

I understand that when fetching an atom feed, you can specify the number of items to return, and the items will have a continuation field that you can use to start subsequent fetches at a position after the items you've already fetched. The question is: how do you find out if there's anything more to fetch without actually trying to fetch more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every atom feed that you get from the Google Reader API will provide a "continuation" token if there's more on the server. If this token is not found in the atom feed, there is no more.